# How can I make a connection for service based on gRPC deployed as containerised microservices on EKS?

Tags: java, spring, grpc, amazon-eks, grpc-java

We have a Test Automation Suite based on Java and we need to make a connection request to gRPC micro service for different RPC calls deployed as containerised services on AWS EKS.

Can someone please share a sample code or blog link to make a grpc call to a service via java?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple HelloWorld example https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld . Take a look at the client (and proto file in https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/src/main/proto/helloworld.proto)

For "containerised services on AWS EKS" I am assuming you are accessing them from inside AWS cloud with network connectivity not being an issue. Make sure the container (pod) ports are accessible from your client.